# How to exclude TWEETS with Tweepy? Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

how's it going?

If I want to exclude retweets from my search query, I use `'searchQuery -filter:retweets'`. Ok?

But how do I exclude tweets, to return only REtweets? `'searchQuery -filter:tweets'` does not work properly or maybe it really does not work.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the `-` before the filter, you are actually filtering out. Like seen in the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators).
So to include retweet you must only put `filter:retweets`